# Linux support for unicode filenames

Tags: linux, filesystems, samba, file-sharing, unicode

I have a couple Linux fileserver running Samba, what do I need to do to support filenames with unicode characters?

- Do particular filesystem have better support for Unicode?

  - Would I get better support by using something other then ext3?
- What do I have to do to get Samba to work with Unicode filenames?
- What other types of issues will I have with Unicode filenames?

  - How about NFS and Unicode?

I am hoping for general information that applies to any distribution, but if it matters assume that the locale of the system is en_US.UTF-8 and the is running either Debian (Lenny), or Ubuntu (Hardy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience with ext3, XFS and reiserfs, there was no difference in Unicode support.

All you have to to is to set the following in the [global] section of your smb.conf

```
UNIX CHARSET = UTF-8
DISPLAY CHARSET = UTF-8
DOS CHARSET = CP850
```

(or CP437 or whatever you like, this is used when talking to DOS or Win9x/3.x clients).

Also, you could read http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/unicode.html